# how to make custom buttons on the sides of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My code allows for sliding a UITableViewCell to the left, it shows a delete button. How do I make something similar on the right that I can customize?

Comment: Please remark if you will use code to generate `UITableViewCell` or a Storyboard.

Comment: UITableViewCell, currently I'm just using the multiple touch, and can enable editing, if there is an easier way on the story board i am open to hearing that

Comment: I mean that in case of `Storyboard` you can have `custom class` for that custom `UITableViewCell`. In that `class` and on `Storyboard` you can add button. In your case you can add button from code. There are many examples how to do that - just google *adding button to custom UITableView Cell*.

Comment: If you want it unique, you can very easily design your own in the IB and use the custom cells in your table. Google *Custom UITableViewCell Interface Builder* and that will get you on the right track.

Comment: Your question is too general. I also have problems like you - I make research and mange to build that button myself. When you have code and something does not working you can ask here.

Comment: See [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift) tutorial of custom cell. It will take about 30-45 minutes to read it. There is also a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) open-source library. It lets you add custom utility buttons on different swipe directions.

In your UITableView's `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method set up needed buttons:

```
cell.leftUtilityButtons = [self leftButtons];
cell.rightUtilityButtons = [self rightButtons];
cell.delegate = self;
```